# pushState is called twice and it rewrites the previous history entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

I have a click event and every time a video is clicked a new entry will be pushed to the history. The problem is that the url changes but also a duplicate entry is entered in the history and it rewrites the previous entry.

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(event) {
    //pushState
    window.history.pushState(data, data.title, data.video_name);
});
```

When the page is loaded it works fine but when I click a new video the problem occurs. So the url changes and in the history is pushed another state. Why is this happening?

On page load. works fine.
[image]

After a new video is clicked. `url changes and the same entry is inserted in the history`.
[image]

If you want to check it go to http://beta.kida.al and click one of the videos below.

Comment: This is kind of the idea of pushing a state to the history: you add a page to the browsers history and the url you see is the url of the latest state. You can use window.onpopstate to serve different history states when the user clicks previous for example.

Comment: Yes I understand the `onpopstate` part but you are saying that this is the way it should work? It's weird because it doesn't happen when you navigate other websites. 

It should change the url but why it adds a new entry to the history when that is the active page?

Comment: using back button works fine in chrome after clicking a video. really not clear what your problem is...or if there even is a problem

Comment: Take this site for example: http://html5.gingerhost.com/
When clicking London or New York, it pushes the history, so when clicking back or forward it changes the content of the page.

Comment: Yes the back buttons work fine. So this is the way it should work? Its nothing wrong here?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the way pop/push state to history should work.